# How to impute values in a data.table by groups?

Tags: r, data.table

Take the following data table:

```
# IMPUTING VALUES
library(data.table)
set.seed(1337)
mydt <- data.table(Year = rep(2000:2005, each = 10),
             Type = c("A","B"),
             Value = 30 + rnorm(60)
             )
naRows <- sample(nrow(mydt),15)
mydt[ naRows, Value := NA]
setkey(mydt,Year,Type)
```

How would I go about imputing the NAs with the median by Year and Type? I have tried the following

```
# computed medians
computedMedians <- mydt[, .(Median = median(Value, na.rm = TRUE)), keyby = .(Year,Type)]
# dataset of just NA rows
dtNAs <- mydt[ is.na(Value), .SD, by = .(Year,Type)]


mydt[ is.na(Value),
      Imputations := dtNAs[computedMedians, nomatch = 0][, Median], 
      by = .(Year,Type)]
mydt
```

but when you run the code, you'll see that it works unless a group is missing data completely, and the computed medians get recycled. Is there a simpler way? or how would you go about getting just the last error fixed?

Comment: `mydt[ , Value := replace(Value, is.na(Value), median(Value, na.rm=TRUE)) , by=.(Year,Type)]` Note that you still have missing values for Year-Type combos with no nonmissing values, like 2005-B

Comment: There are numerous ways to impute missing data (EM, kNN, mean, etc). You have chosen by median. The median of `NA` is `NA`. Unless you specify a backup approach, there's no appropriate answer here. One possibility, would be to use the median of the entire dataset as a missing median. Whether this is appropriate or depends on your assumptions about the data and whether such a hierarchy exists.

Comment: Answers like these make me both happy and sad. Happy because your solution is both elegant and comprehensive. But sad because I spent way more time getting to my question than the 59 seconds it took for your answer to appear. Thank you Frank. This is much appreciated.

Comment: As for the NA's, I will take a second pass using another method. My actual data set has qualifiers that specify more granular and granular subsets of data, so the second pass will be on a much larger subset than the first pass.

Comment: Hey, the time writing the question was well spent. It was only possible to answer quickly because the question was clear. :)

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer updating the rows without copying the entire column, then:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
cols = c("Year", "Type")
dt[is.na(Value), Value := dt[.BY, median(Value, na.rm=TRUE), on=cols], by=c(cols)]
```

`.BY` is a special symbol which is a named list containing the groups. Although this requires a join with the entire data.table every time, it should be quite fast, as it's searching for only one group.

Comment: Is `dt[.BY, median(Value, na.rm=TRUE), on=cols]` used to create an empty data table?  Just trying to pick this apart.  I ran that alone and it was empty

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do `dt[is.na(Value), print(.BY), by=c(cols)]` first, followed by `dt[is.na(Value), print(dt[.BY, Value, on=cols]), by=c(cols)]` on the original `dt`. It should help clear things up..

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to make a secondary table; it can be done inside a single by-group call:

```
mydt[, 
  Value := replace(Value, is.na(Value), median(Value, na.rm=TRUE))
, by=.(Year,Type)]
```

This imputation doesn't guarantee that all missing values are filled (e.g., 2005-B is still `NA`).